# RiverPod StateNotifier to notify listeners without change to state

Tags: flutter

I have this need:

A 'home' button clicked on Widget A, notifies another Widget B to scroll to the top. I' ve created the notifier as:

```
final showFirstViewportNotifierPod = StateProvider.autoDispose<int>((ref) {
  return -1;
});
```

Everytime the home button is clicked:

```
ref.read(showFirstViewportNotifierPod.notifier).state = 0;
```

Obviously, this way Widget B is not notified for a repeated click, as there is no change in state.

I 'fixed' this in two ways on button click:

```
ref.read(showFirstViewportNotifierPod.notifier).state = -1;
ref.read(showFirstViewportNotifierPod.notifier).state = 0;
```

or

```
ref.read(showFirstViewportNotifierPod.notifier).update((state) => state + 1);
```

with Widget B rebuilding only if the state is not -1 and changes to any value.

I'm not happy with this 'hack'. Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you're confusing a StateNotifier for data when you want a different notification schedule than simply changing state?  What is the notification depending on?  Maybe *that* state belongs in a state notifier!

Comment: If you just want an event bus, you can have a provider that exposes a notifier with a wrapper around .notifyListeners(), and not even use the state.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, do you have a code snippet, this will help...

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, I create a `StateNotifier` with a boolean type and switch the state whenever I want to notify.

```
final someProvider =
StateNotifierProvider<SomeNotifier, bool>((ref) => SomeNotifier());

class SomeNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  SomeNotifier() : super(true);

  void trigger() {
    state = !state;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this is far more elegant!